# Jquery Mobile - pagebeforehide - can't get event to fire

Tags: jquery, mobile, event-handling, mobile-website

I'm trying to fire an event in JqueryMobile when navigating within a multipage. I can't get the event to fire. Anybody can help?

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
    <div data-role="content">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>View internal page called <a href="#2ndPage">2ndPage</a></p>
    </div>   
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="2ndPage">
    <div data-role="content">
            <p>SubContent</p>
            <p><a href="#mainPage">MainPage</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my script:

```
$('#mainPage').bind('pagebeforehide', function (event, ui)
             {
             alert ("leaving MainPage");
             });
```

Thanks for helping!

Frequent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use "live" instead of "bind"

```
$('#mainPage').live('pagebeforehide', function (event, ui)
{
    alert ("leaving MainPage");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well. No where in the source of my jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js is there any mention of "pagebeforehide".

I have a feeling this hasn't been integrated in the current release yet.